# Display One Div at a Time and Disable Active Div's Button

Tags: javascript

As you can see, 3 `divs` are created using JavaScript when their respective buttons are clicked. I pass their values and then use those to create the content. I am not sure if this is the best way... but anyway.

The problem is that the `divs` keep appending. I only want to show one `div` at a time, and I also want to disable the active `div's` button. I've seen that you can use something like `document.querySelector('button[onclick]').disabled = true;`, but I am unsure of how to make it dynamically work because it would have to be set to `false` once any of the other buttons are clicked.

Here is my JavaScript that is responsible for creating the content:

```
function showDiv(name) {
    var selectedButton = name.value;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'myDiv';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    if (selectedButton === 'home') {
        div.innerHTML = 'Hi, this is a test for the ' + selectedButton + ' div.';

    } else if (selectedButton === 'about') {
        div.innerHTML = 'Hi, this is a test for the ' + selectedButton + ' div.';

    } else if (selectedButton === 'contact') {
        div.innerHTML = 'Hi, this is a test for the ' + selectedButton + ' div.';
    }
}
```

My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wwen39o9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wwen39o9/3/

In short, add one div to the html:

`<div id="myDiv"></div>`

Give buttons a class `navbutton`:

Javascript:

```
function showDiv(me) {
    $('.navbutton').prop('disabled', false);
    $(me).prop('disabled', true);
    $('#myDiv').html('Hi, this is a test for my ' + $(me).val() + ' div.');
}
```

Pure JS version without jQuery:

```
function showDiv(me) {
    var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if (buttons[i].className == 'navbutton')
            buttons[i].disabled = false;   
    }

    me.disabled = true;
    div.innerHTML = 'Test for ' + me.value;
}
```

Comment: I'm liking this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to set an active button in a group of buttons:

If they are confined to a wrapper:

```
function setActive(selectedButton){
    var parent = selectedButton.parentNode;
    var children = parent.getElementsByTagName('button');
    var child_ct = children.length - 1;
    while (child_ct) {
        children[child_ct].disabled = false;
        child_ct--;
    }

    selectedButton.disabled = true;
}
```

Or by giving all a class like .nav-btn

```
function setActive(selectedButton) {
    var parent = selectedButton.parentNode;
    var children = parent.getElementsByClassName('nav-btn');
    var child_ct = children.length - 1;
    while (child_ct) {
        children[child_ct].disabled = false;
        child_ct--;
    }

    selectedButton.disabled = true;
}
```

A good way to swap out div:

Check if div exists. Replace content if so, create div if not.

```
function showDiv(content) {
    var div = document.getElementById('the-div');
    if (div) {

       //May be better to remove children, then append content, but...
       div.innerHTML = content
    } else {
       var the_div = document.createElement('div');
       the_div.id = 'the-div';
       the_div.innerHTML = content;
       document.appendChild(the_div);
    }

}
```

So:

```
function handleClick() {
   setActive(this);
   if (this.name === 'home') {
      showDiv('Information about being home');
   }

}

<button onclick="handleClick">
```

Answer (score 0):

The append method should be call only if we did not found one.

Something like

```
function showDiv(name) {
    var selectedButton = name.value;
    var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    if(!div) {
      document.createElement('div');
      div.id = 'myDiv';
      document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check the number of `div` elements on page

Or why not to do it like following. At the beginning we have an empty `div` with `id="myDiv"` and then we are just changing its content with JavaScript. Have a look at [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wwen39o9/2/).

**HTML**

```
<button value="home" onclick="showDiv(this);">Home</button>
<button value="about" onclick="showDiv(this);">About</button>
<button value="contact" onclick="showDiv(this);">Contact</button>

<!-- create an empty div -->
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showDiv(name) {
    var selectedButton = name.value;
    var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');

    if (selectedButton === 'home') {
        div.innerHTML = 'Hi, this is a test for the ' + selectedButton + ' div.';

    } else if (selectedButton === 'about') {
        div.innerHTML = 'Hi, this is a test for the ' + selectedButton + ' div.';

    } else if (selectedButton === 'contact') {
        div.innerHTML = 'Hi, this is a test for the ' + selectedButton + ' div.';
    }
}
```